# When I group by linq query does not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, entity-framework-core-3.0

```
using (var tigerContext = new TigerContext())
        {
            var stockRemaningList = from stocks in tigerContext.Stock
                join item in tigerContext.ItemsSum
                    on stocks.LOGICALREF equals item.STOCKREF  into temp 
                from x in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()

                group x by new { stocks}
                into s
                select new StocksRemaning
                {
                    StockCode = s.Key.stocks.CODE,
                    StockRef = s.Key.stocks.LOGICALREF,
                    StockName = s.Key.stocks.NAME,
                    ActualStock = s.Sum(i=>i.ONHAND)

                };
            return stockRemaningList.ToList();


        }
```

this is my error. How I can solve this error

> ```
> The LINQ expression 'GroupBy<TransparentIdentifier<Stock, ItemsSum>, <>f__AnonymousType10<Stock>, ItemsSum>(
>     source: LeftJoin<Stock, ItemsSum, int, TransparentIdentifier<Stock, ItemsSum>>(
>         outer: DbSet<Stock>, 
>         inner: DbSet<ItemsSum>, 
>         outerKeySelector: (s) => s.LOGICALREF, 
>         innerKeySelector: (ı) => ı.STOCKREF, 
>         resultSelector: (s, ı) => new TransparentIdentifier<Stock, ItemsSum>(
>             Outer = s, 
>             Inner = ı
>         )), 
>     keySelector: (ti) => new { stocks = ti.Outer }, 
>     elementSelector: (ti) => ti.Inner)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the anonymous type in your `group by` clause, that way the EF engine will have no problem translating it into actual SQL.

As an advice, I would suggest you get used to giving more meaningful names, for example `from leftJoined in tempJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()`. That way other coders or yourself in the future would have no need to ask "What the hell was X? and S?"

```
using (var tigerContext = new TigerContext())
{
    var stockRemaningList = 
        from stocks in tigerContext.Stock
        join item in tigerContext.ItemsSum on stocks.LOGICALREF equals item.STOCKREF  into tempJoin 
        from leftJoined in tempJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
        group leftJoined by stocks into grouped
        select new StocksRemaning
        {
            StockCode = grouped.Key.CODE,
            StockRef = grouped.Key.LOGICALREF,
            StockName = grouped.Key.NAME,
            ActualStock = grouped.Sum(i=>i.ONHAND)
        };
    return stockRemaningList.ToList();
}
```